# Why won't my toilet flush right? Did our plumbers not put something back right?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

We've had issues in the past about having the sewage line get backed up.  We just had the plumber here almost a week ago to replace the water line.  Now our toilet won't flush right.  It flushes all the water into the bowl but it just stays there and slowly goes out of the bowl but it still leaves solid waste behind.  We have tried our normal "fixes" when the line gets back up but it's still not doing right.  We plug the shower when we take one so the water doesn't drain and then wait overnight to flush but it does the same but then we unplug the tub and the water there drains perfectly fine.  What I'm wondering is if the plumbers did something under the house that affects the pressure of the toilet flushing.

Comment: if you were having a sewer backup, why would they replace the water supply line? Do you mean they replaced a section of the sewer line?

Comment: No we had a clean out put in outside and the water line was galvanized steal and got hit in the process of digging so we had to have the line replaced.

Comment: There's no such thing as "pressure" when it comes to toilet flushing; its based on gravity and the volume of water coming into the bowl.  it sounds like you still have a clog in your sewer somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you had "the sewage line get backed up" all along and didn't do anything to fix it (replacing the water line doesn't) then the sewage line will only get worse.

As for your tub (I think you want me to guess you shower in the tub instead of having both a tub and a separate shower), it probably connects to the sewage line after the clog that affects your toilet.

Comment: we've had the sewage line cleaned out

Comment: If it is backing up again, it's time to put a camera down it and see what's up - could be a collapse or something along those lines.

Comment: It sounds to me like this clog is local to the toilet, though you may have other issues. Consider removing the toilet, then investigate the trapway from both ends and see if you can easily pour water into the drain pipe under the toilet. You'll need a new wax ring to replace the toilet afterwards.

Comment: @bcworkz - Remove the toilet and look for the flushed toy stuck in one of the bends.